# I created a service in Java but it doesn't run in the background

Tags: java, android, service

I am trying to create a simple service in java that will run in the background. I want to play a song on the phone even though the app is closed. I read some articles and watched tutorials but my service still stops when I close the app.

1) I changed my manifest

```
<service
            android:name="com.example.myapplication.ServiceSound"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>
```

2) I returned START_STICKY

This is manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.example.myapplication.ServiceSound"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>
    </application>
```

This is the service

```
public class ServiceSound extends Service {
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

And this is how I start the service in MainActivity.java

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),ServiceSound.class));
```

Comment: whats your android os version?

Comment: you need foreground service for that

Comment: And how do I use foreground service?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Broadcast Receiver.
So now 
1- Create broadcast receiver class and call your Service class.

```
  public class MyBroadcaseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       context.startService(new Intent(context,ServiceSound.class));
       Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: BroadCast is started");
   }
}
```

2- Your Service class define this

```
       public static String str_receiver = "Your_Package_Name.receiver";
```

on startCommand start your broadcast class

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,MyBroadcaseReceiver.class);
        sendBroadcast(intent1);
        return START_STICKY;


       }
```

Now in your MainActivity class create an object for broadcast 
`private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;`

inside `onCreate()` define the object
`broadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcaseReceiver();`

Finaly call `onResume()` and `onPause()` inside the MainActivity.

```
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyService.str_receiver));
    }
```

```
   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

    }
```

Don't forget to call broadcast reciever in your Manifest file

```
           <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcaseReceiver"></receiver>
```

Comment: The problem you may have is continuously running The service even after you close your app. and i don't know how to solve that ):